# Use javascript or php for calculations?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm a student and we have this course in which we develop a bigger application throughout the semester. I'm writing front-end which is all fun and games but i came to think whether to write calculations in JavaScript or in PHP.

I did some googling and maybe because English is not my mother tongue i found no results about this topic and maybe discussions about it are not so popular. Anyways, on to my problem.

I'm creating dynamically text-fields with javascript and they all have some value in the end when the "ready" button is pressed. Now there's also an option to select how many rounds will be played and whether the names will be shuffled or not. Now my question is really straight forward - should shuffling be done in javascript, same goes for the if-conditions (whether the checkbox is checked; are there enough players etc), or should these things be done in PHP. Both are capable of doing it just the matter of where. Would love some explanation or links towards this.

My pros for javascript would be that i don't really know PHP much and i could put all the things i want to send for backend developer in an array and tell him at which position in an array the specific thing is.

My cons will be if this is not the method which is used in practice since we're graded according to best practices.

Comment: if you understand that javascript is execute on the pc of the user  (client-side) while on the other hand php is executed server-side, it should be easy for you to find out what you need to use for what.

Comment: If i'm going to post information to another page via php then it matters, doesen't it? I could give array out from javascript and shuffle it in php and post it to another page, although i could shuffle it in javascript, give array to php and post it. The question was which one is used more in practice and why. Don't really understand the downvote.

Comment: the fact is, on the client side, the shuffle can be manipulated and changed to what ever the client wishes with just a little knowledge of the technology. the question is, do you care if it is messed around with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any particular **need** for there to be a server? Do you have multiple players and need to coordinate between them? Do you need to persist data and perform internal calculations that should not be exposed to the client? Do you have secret information on the server which is required for calculation, and isn't available to the client?

If not, then all calculations on the client are just fine. Note that going back and forth to a server for every single action in the game can be quite slow (especially if you're not doing it from `localhost`).

More advanced approaches include doing the calculations on **both** the client and the server, and be optimistic that both calculations would return the same value (i.e. do calculation on client, and send calculation to be done on the server, calculation is done on client, display result immediately, server response returns with calculation, if there are differences, change the result, if not, continue as if nothing happened).

Also, you don't have to know PHP to build a server. A server is not exclusively written in PHP, in fact, if you're familiar with JavaScript, you can use **[Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/)** to build your server.

Comment: Pretty great explanation. We're gonna need server to store data in the database and post data from one page to another. I am able to do all the current calculations in the JavaScript. How should the data be presented to the PHP if it's coming from JavaScript? Should i just add it in the array (ar[0] = bool, ar[1] = array2, etc..) and throw it to the PHP or are there some special niches about it?

Comment: You can use AJAX to send data from JavaScript to PHP and vice versa. Also, traditional forms work just fine in case it's a suitable UI for your game.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your information, i'll mark this as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have all the information required to do the calculations in the front-end, it is better to do in Javascript (i.e frontend) so that, you don't even need to contact server.

If you need some other data (from backend) to do the calculations, it is better to do the calculations in PHP and send the results to front-end.

Comment: i strongly disagree.. even if you know everything clientside, the client can without a problem manipulate the calculation. that should always be considered. doing "as much as possible" client-side might lead to serious security issues

Comment: If client is compromised, even if you do the calculations on the server side, there is no guarantee that client shows that data that you want (means, that you calculated on server).

Comment: so if you would program a webshop, you send the calculation for the sum of the products to the client and then send it back, so you dont have to make the calculation server-side? what stops the client to just say it was less then it actually would be? same thing would go for a game highscore or something similar

Comment: its about the client potentially manipulating the server. not the client manipulating himself